# viewControllers property of UINavigationController return different objects in IOS7 and iOS8

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8

In iOS 7 I got the last pushed view controller in this code:

```
id controller = [self.navigationController.viewControllers lastObject];
```

But same code in iOS 8 return another controller (root view controller for this navigation controller). How I can fix it?

Comment: That shouldn't give you any different results in iOS 8 than it did in 7. Where do you have this line. You need to provide more context.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem currently while running tests and checking if the view controllers are correctly added to the navigation stack. I noticed, that by removing the push animation

```
navigationController.viewControllers
```

would return the correct view controller. I assume, in iOS8 you'll have to wait for the animation to finish until you can get the correct object out of the viewControllers-property.

You could just try with

```
[navigationController setViewControllers:array animated:NO]
```